# Woocommerce / Product Columns on Shop Loop / Responsive

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, loop

I'm trying to make the following layout

1 Column / Mobile
2 Column / Tab
3 Column / Desktop

I have set up the customizer so that there are two rows, and three columns.
This works on desktop, and I can hack the CSS so that each product takes up one row. Beautiful.

However, on tablet view, I get the following issue:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsvcidk9fx54scy/Screenshot%202021-04-20%20at%2012.37.27.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/448aqurcf8bq5g0/Screenshot%202021-04-20%20at%2012.37.41.png?dl=0

The first items in the row have a clear:both property, but removing it does not fix my issue. I can't add padding or margin, because that messes up the layout as well.

I would need some kind of a filter, that changes the loop so that when the viewport is tablet sized, then  the 2 column layout is used by Woocommerce.

Is there such a thing?

Thanks!

SOURCE URL: `https://cinemastill.ethermedia.hu/webshop/`

Issue visible at 777px width.

Comment: Without the ability to check the code, it will be hard to identify your issue. Do you have a link to the site we could use?

Comment: @Anake.me Thanks for having a look. Added the staging site's link to the bottom.